# Spring Apps on Bluemix throwing SqlExceptionHelper - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803 if both Applications have slight difference in Model Files

Tags: spring, hibernate, db2, ibm-cloud

I have 4 Spring Applications running on Bluemix using the same DashDB (DB2 Cloud) Database. If there is a slight difference in the model class, for instance, I have a constructor which I use only in App A. But If I update this constructor in App A, Unless and Until I update it in App B as well, I'm getting SqlExceptionHelper - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803. Which is a Primary Key Constraint Violation Exception. Even though the update has nothing to do with Primary Keys.

It seems that unless and until both the Applications are having the ditto model files, I'm getting this Exception

Comment: Check the error code and resolution: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21508894

Comment: The solution is making sure that all model files in all applications are exact copies. My question is why is that necessary and how is it related to primary key

Comment: Are you using dashdb analytics or dashdb transactional?

Comment: I am using DashDB Transactional